# 404 when trying to deploy basic Flask application with WSGI on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, apache, flask, raspberry-pi, mod-wsgi

I've been following the instructions on http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/deploying/mod_wsgi/ to get my Flask application to be deployed on Apache through WSGI on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian, but whatever I try, I keep getting a 404-error on the location I've specified. I used the info on various webpages I could find (especially the instructions on http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Serving-a-Python-Flask-Web-Application-via-Apache-Webserver-in-Raspberry-Pi.aspx), but nothing seems to work out.

Logged in as root, I created a directory `/var/www/flasktest` in which I put two files:

`flasktest.py`, containing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

and `flasktest.wsgi` containing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/flasktest')

from flasktest import app as application
```

I then did a `chmod ugo+x` on both files (don't know if that's necessary, though).

I also created `/etc/apache2/sites-available/001-flasktest.conf` containing

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost

  WSGIDaemonProcess flasktest threads=5
  WSGIScriptAlias /flasktest/ /var/www/flasktest/flasktest.wsgi

  <Directory /var/www/flask/flasktest>
    WSGIProcessGroup flasktest
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I executed `a2enmod wsgi`, `a2ensite 001-flasktest.conf` and `service apache2 reload`. Every command was executed as root user.

When I go now go to `http://localhost/flasktest` I get a 404-error. `http://localhost` gives me the default Apache-page, so apparently Apache is running correctly. As far as I can see, Apache does not generate any error messages at all.

I really don't know what goes wrong: what makes the 404 come up? Can somebody help me out here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you perhaps need to put `app.run()` in your WSGI file? I'm not familiar with WSGI _or_ Apache, so I'm not much help here, but that could be something to try.

Comment: shouldn't you be going to just localhost rather than going to the absolute path where you files are saved ? After all your app.route is defined as '/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check your WSGIScriptAlias variable- That should be ([according to the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/deploying/mod_wsgi/))

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/yourapplication/yourapplication.wsgi
```

Whereas you have

```
WSGIScriptAlias /yourapplicaiton/ /var/www/yourapplication/yourapplication.wsgi
```

As Philip Tzou also mentioned, your `Directory` path may not be correct, either.

Further, sometimes the server name `localhost` can give you problems. Use `127.0.0.1:80` instead.

Comment: The solution turned out to be in a combination of your two suggestions (although I did not have to specify the port number after 127.0.0.1), and in the mistake that @PhilipTzou pointed me at. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Awesome :) glad to hear, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you passed a wrong path to `<Directory />` accidentally. Try change `/etc/apache2/sites-available/001-flasktest.conf` to this:

```
<Directory /var/www/flasktest>
...
</Directory>
```

Also you can take a look of apache error log to see what exactly happened.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed was part of the problem.